# How to search for multiple strings in xcode project programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Search navigator on the left panel or (cmd shift f) seems to be the solution for one file but I need to search some 260 files for there occurrence in an xcode project.

Is there a way to programmatically to find where more than one files are present in a project. How can I browse through the project .xcodeproj file ?

Comment: Shift-Cmd-F searches every file in the project.

Comment: I want to search for some files in the project programmatically. It means that I want to know how some files (like images or xib) present in the Project say Project1 folder are actually being used by a project. I want to traverse through the Project1.xcworkspace file to see for file references.

Comment: @rmaddy see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641774/search-multiple-strings-in-xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to search in the xcode then run below command.

```
    grep -Ir --include =\*.{h,m} "pattern" *
```

Comment: Why would you choose to exclude .h and .m files? I would think those are the ones you want to search.