# Search multiple strings in Xcode

Tags: regex, xcode, find

Is there any way that I can search something like `string1 || string2` in my Xcode project and or in a single file?

When doing such I want Xcode to highlight wherever it finds `string1` OR `string2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can just use a regular expression, e.g. `string|string2`.

For multiple file search across whole project:

[image]

For single file search then just use the normal find and change the Find Options from Textual to Regular Expression:

[image]

Comment: is there anyway I can search only in my current file? Can you also include that in your answer? ( FYI I just updated my question)

Comment: Sure - same method.

Comment: but in the search bar above at the top of the class. regular expression doesn't work. It does work in the search where you can do for the entire project

Comment: You have to click on `Find Options` (next to the magnifying glass) and change `Textual` to `Regular Expression`.

Comment: I've already done that and it works fine **across the entire project**. But how can I limit it to search only the current class I am seeing?

Comment: You need to use the normal single file Find at the top of the Editor pane (not the project find) - Command-F brings it up if you can't already see it.

Comment: That I know as well and tried that. But the regular expression doesn't function there. It **ONLY** functions when I do from the project find. Does regular expression work for you in Editor pane? I don't see an option to something to transition from `Textual` to `Regular Expression`. There is ONLY *find* and *replace*

Comment: Look at the magnifying glass next to the search term - there is an arrow next to it - click on the arrow... (see updated answer above).